# Do mitochondria contain the genes to specify themselves?

Tags: cell-biology, mitochondria, dna-replication

My book says : 
"Mitochondria contain their own genetic material so when a cell divides, the mitochondria replicate themselves under the control of the nucleus."
The book means that the mitochondria contain the genes which produce the mitochondria right  ?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is a bit more complicated than that. Mitochondria contain their own [genome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrion#Genome) called mitochondrial DNA (mtDNA), encoding 13 proteins that are part of respiratory complexes I, III, IV, and V, 22 [transfer RNAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_RNA) (tRNAs), and two [ribosomal RNAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosomal_RNA) (rRNAs). The separate tRNAs and rRNAs are necessary because the mitochondrial genome uses a [slightly different genetic code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_mitochondrial_genetics) than the nuclear genome.

So, the mitochondria contain nearly all of the genes necessary to construct the respiratory chain, as well as the machinery to translate the [mRNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messenger_RNA) into protein. However, it does *not* contain any of the genes necessary to actually replicate the mtDNA (DNA polymerases, etc.) or construct the mitochondrion itself - synthesize the components of the different membranes, arrange the membranes in their required conformation, chaperones to assemble the complexes of the respiratory chain, etc. - these are all encoded in the nuclear DNA.